# Visual Studio 2012 Not Working Properly - Unexpected Error

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, visual-studio-2012, ssis

My visual studio is acting weird. When I try to open a fresh unit test it freezes, gives me three options (close, restart, debugg), and does it again. When I open an existing file; they open but do not Run or Execute.
When trying to test or debug, I recieve a message that states "Unexpected error detected. Check the Tests Output Pane for details.".

Heading over to the output pane I get this message(Show output from tests):

```
" System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ValidateArg.NotNull[T](T arg, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ValidateArg.NotNullOrEmpty[T](IEnumerable`1 arg, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSProjectExtensions.CompareNormalizedPath(String source, String target)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSProjectExtensions.GetKeyOutputForIVsOutputGroup(IVsOutputGroup outputGroup)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSProjectExtensions.GetProjectOutputPath(IVsProjectCfg2 projectConfig, String groupName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.VSProjectExtensions.GetKeyOutputForGroup(IVsSolutionBuildManager buildManager, IVsProject project, String groupName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.VsTestContainer.get_Source()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.VsTestContainer.CreateTimeStamp()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.VsTestContainer..ctor(ITestContainerDiscoverer discoverer, ILogger log, IVsProject project, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IVsAppContainerUtilities appContainerUtilities)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.VsAdapters.VsProjectOutputContainerDiscoverer.<get_TestContainers>b__0(IVsProject p)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerDiscovererExtension.GetSortedContainers(ITestContainerDiscoverer discoverer)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Controller.TestContainerProvider.GetContainersFromDiscoverer(ITestContainerDiscoverer discoverer)"
```

I have tried updating my SSDT version to the latest and that has not been of help to me. Please help I depend on this program for day to day usage.

Comment: What's your SSDT version ? 11.1.30822.0 had a bug in unit testing which shows the exact same error. Upgrading to 11.1.30914.0 fixed it for a coworker.

Comment: 11.1.31009.1 is the version

Comment: Hm. I have no info about that version I'm afraid

Comment: Where can I check the latest version of the SSDT? I installed the latest I would like to see if VS is recognizing it

Comment: In the Visual Studio About page, SSDT is one of the Installed Products.